# Traer datos con jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Hola buenas tardes estimados, miren el problema aqui es que intento traer datos desde mi base de datos para autocompletar un formulario pero me da error o me no me trae nada
revise la query y si me arrojan datos, tambien use un console.log para visualizar el array de datos y si los muestra, pero al momento de convertir ese array en datos que podamos manejar a mi antojo truena la instruccion

Muestro el codigo para ver si le pueden dar una hojeada

Este es el codigo de JQuery

introducir el código aquí

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selecciona_admmin').change(function () {
        $('#selecciona_admmin option:selected').each(function () {
            admin = $(this).val();
            accion(admin)
        })

    })
})

function accion(admin) {
    var add = admin;
    if (admin != 0) {
        $('#formulatio_actualiza_admin').show(200);
        $.post("php/Cargas_estructura.php", {
            Obtener_datos_admin: add
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data)

            var admin = [];
            for(var i in data){
                admin.push(data.nombre_admin);
            }
            admin.push(data.nombre_admin);
            $('#nombre_admin_act').val(admin);

        })
    } else {
        $('#formulatio_actualiza_admin').hide(200);
    }
}



  

      <?php
        
        if (isset($_POST['Obtener_datos_admin'])) {
            $id_admin = $_POST['Obtener_datos_admin'];
            include_once 'MetodosUsuarios.php';
            $metodos = new MetodosUsuarios();
            $datos_admin= $metodos->Consulta_AUTO_Admin($id_admin);
            $datos = json_encode($datos_admin);
            echo $datos;
            
        }
        
        
        
          public function Consulta_AUTO_Admin($id_admin)
          {
            include_once 'conexion.php';
            $conexion = new ConexionSQL();
            $con = $conexion->ObtenerConexionBD();
            $query = "SELECT 
                      id_admin
                      ,nombre_admin
                      ,nombre_corto
                      ,nombre_sigla
                      ,estatus
                      ,user_alta
                      ,fecha_alta
                      ,user_mod
                      ,fecha_mod
                      ,user_baja
                      ,fecha_baja
                      ,unidad
                      ,telefono
                      ,direccion
                      FROM Administracion
                      WHERE id_admin = $id_admin AND estatus = 'A'";
            $prepare = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
            if ($prepare) {
              while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($prepare, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $fila[] = $row;
              }
              if (isset($fila)) {
                return $fila;
                $conexion->CerrarConexion($con);
              } else {
                return null;
                $conexion->CerrarConexion($con);
              }
            } else {
              return print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
              $conexion->CerrarConexion($con);
            }
          }
        
        
        ?>
```

Si esperando que puedan ayudarme , realmente no se que onda xd

Comment: Prueba consultar los datos con `ajax`.

Comment: Ya lo solucione bro, solo me falto agregar en php
esta sentencia 
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
en el antes de mandar los datos por echo 
despues solo tenia que recorrerlos con el for de jquery usando push para traer el dato en especifico

Answer (score 0):

Solucion

```
     <php

    if (isset($_POST['Obtener_datos_admin'])) {
    $id_admin = $_POST['Obtener_datos_admin'];
    include_once 'MetodosUsuarios.php';
    $metodos = new MetodosUsuarios();
    $datos_admin= $metodos->Consulta_AUTO_Admin($id_admin);
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($datos_admin);
    
    }

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selecciona_admmin').change(function () {
        $('#selecciona_admmin option:selected').each(function () {
            admin = $(this).val();
            accion(admin)
        })
  
    })
  })
  
  function accion(admin) {
    var admin = admin;
    if (admin != 0) {
    $('#formulatio_actualiza_admin').show(200);
    $.post("php/Ac_estructuras.php",{Obtener_datos_admin: admin}, function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
  
        var id_admin = [];
        var nombre_admin = [];
        var nombre_corto = [];
        var unidad = [];
        var telefono = [];
        var direccion = [];
        
  
        for (var i in data) {
            id_admin.push(data.id_admin);
            nombre_admin.push(data.nombre_admin);
            nombre_corto.push(data.nombre_corto);
            unidad.push(data.unidad);
            telefono.push(data.telefono);
            direccion.push(data.direccion);
     
          
      }
  
        if(id_admin != null){
                    $("#nombre_admin_act").val(nombre_admin[0]);
                    $("#Abreb_act").val(nombre_corto[0]);
                    $("#unidad_act").val(unidad[0]);
                    $("#telefono_admin").val(telefono[0]);
                    $("#direc_act").val(direccion[0]);
  
        }else{
            alert('Los datos del usuario no estan disponibles.')
        }})
    } else {
        $('#formulatio_actualiza_admin').hide(200);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Explica brevemente qué hace tu código: aunque lo que hiciste te ha sido útil a ti y entiendes su funcionamiento, puede que otros usuarios tengan el mismo inconveniente, y luego puede que lean tu código y no comprendan su funcionamiento. Lee [answer].